# Old Phone Text Messaging

Tags: python, dictionary

My code is

```
def search(n):
    lis = []
    pad = {1: ['.', ',''?', '!', ':'], 2: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 3: ['D', 'E', 'F'], 4: ['G', 'H', 'I'], 5: ['J', 'K', 'L']
        , 6: ['M', 'N', 'O'], 7: ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'], 8: ['T', 'U', 'V'], 9: ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], 0: ' '}
    for i in n:
        for key,values in pad.items():
            if i.upper() in values:
                lis.append(key)
    return lis


def main():
     m = input("Enter String")
     print(search(m))
main()
```

my output is

```
Enter String - hello world
[4, 3, 5, 5, 6, 0, 9, 6, 7, 5, 3]
```

It gives output as the single key only. However I want output as    [44,33,555,555,666,9,666,777,555,3]

Comment: PLease add some details how to reach your desired output. Not sure where you get those 2x4

Comment: Find the index of `i` in `values` and repeat it that many times +1. `lis.append(str(key) * (values.index(i)+1))`

Comment: @0stone0  for typing 'H' you have to press 4 key 2 time, so that's why 44 , for 'E' you press 3 two times and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you after you find the key, you only append the key once.

You will need to add the logic to duplicate the key string several times.

I only added one line and modified one line of your original code. Hope this helps.

```
def search(n):
    lis = []
    pad = {1: ['.', ',''?', '!', ':'], 2: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 3: ['D', 'E', 'F'], 4: ['G', 'H', 'I'], 5: ['J', 'K', 'L']
        , 6: ['M', 'N', 'O'], 7: ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'], 8: ['T', 'U', 'V'], 9: ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], 0: ' '}
    for i in n:
        for key, values in pad.items():
            if i.upper() in values:
                temp = str(key) * (values.index(i.upper()) + 1)  // added
                lis.append(temp)   // modified
    return lis


def main():
     m = input("Enter String")
     print(search(m))
main()
```

Comment: While this works, this approach is twice inefficient, first because looping over the dictionary to search the character is inefficient, then because using `list.index` has the same issue. This is not critical for a small program but definitely not a good habit to learn ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comments @mozway , I think your solution has much better performance.

Comment: You're welcome, I just commented because I feel it's important that beginners understand the concepts of code complexity and start learning with good practices in mind. Searching keys by values repeatedly is an anti-pattern that should be avoided ;)

Answer (score 4):

Refactor your code to build a reverse dictionary to directly map the code from the characters instead of repeatedly searching (this is inefficient):

```
pad = {1: ['.', ',''?', '!', ':'],
       2: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
       3: ['D', 'E', 'F'],
       4: ['G', 'H', 'I'],
       5: ['J', 'K', 'L'],
       6: ['M', 'N', 'O'],
       7: ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'],
       8: ['T', 'U', 'V'],
       9: ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
       0: ' '}

mapper = {c: str(num)*i  for num, l in pad.items()
          for i,c in enumerate(l, start=1)}
# {'.': '1', ',?': '11', '!': '111', ':': '1111', 'A': '2' ...}


def str_to_code(s):
    return [mapper[c.upper()] for c in s]

str_to_code('hello world')
```

output:

```
['44', '33', '555', '555', '666', '0', '9', '666', '777', '555', '3']
```

Comment: [Online *tio.run* Demo](https://tio.run/##TZBZa8MwEITf9Su29EFWMaZOb0MI6X3fdwjB2AoxOLaRZUoJ@e2uRqIgP4xW8y3r1TS/elFXO33fpDkNaRUnNOERD4mHnI9wbkASPg0ZuW@AljHcY8iJh3aATuGeQc49tAt0AfcScuWhPaBruDeQWw/tA93BvYc8eOgA6BHuE@QZ8uLxQ/BXuG@Qdw8dAX3A/YR8Qb49vp0QJ75mbJk2jVTIJUuo1SqouqXYKojmtSJTh1RSUZHJLiq0XLaB@B9BrqcIMzRI0ytVqmVQhmZOqvQwFmu2SSuTtflZbAMf2TJ2odsydtm72l7GuAw4RVFk9mO5nGOvma5nWZ3LoBWJ3UBJ3amKJu4BkyzqcAZiareyO7VTxpRsu1Kb9/kz@EKWZU0/tSpzLlijikoHrlP0/R8)

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach:

```
def search(n):
lis = []
pad = {1: ['.', ',''?', '!', ':'], 2: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 3: ['D', 'E', 'F'], 4: ['G', 'H', 'I'], 5: ['J', 'K', 'L']
    , 6: ['M', 'N', 'O'], 7: ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'], 8: ['T', 'U', 'V'], 9: ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], 0: ' '}
for i in n:
    for key,values in pad.items():
        if i.upper() in values:
            lis.append(1111*key*int(values.index(i.upper()) == 3) +
                       111*key*int(values.index(i.upper()) == 2) +
                       11*key*int(values.index(i.upper()) == 1) +
                       1*key*int(values.index(i.upper()) == 0)
                       )
return lis


def main():
    m = input("Enter String")
    print(search(m))
main()
```

But I think the approach of [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74069869/3564720) is better.